# Eclipse hangs during debugging with "Evaluating" thread

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I miss some good keyword for google to find something useful, so I need to ask here...

During a debugging session with Eclipse the thread under inspection turns into "Evaluating" mode during the inspection of a variable. The variable is shown with its input once, but the thread hangs afterwards and can only be terminated. The content of the variables is not shown another time. Trying to terminate the evaluation with a right click on the thread and selecting "Terminate Evaluation" brings the message:

"Attempts to terminate an evaluation can only stop a series of statements. The
currently executing statement (such asa method invocation) cannot be interrupted."

What is going on here? Can I release and restart the thread on the same position or is terminating the only option? Is this behavior cause by the content of the variable or is it caused by something else?

Comment: What language are you debugging? With which plugin? How (local or remote)?

Comment: what is the exact expression you try to evaluate? If it is a method can it cause an issue like throwing exception, etc.

Comment: Just throwing out some ideas; Have you tried changing breakpoint properties to suspend vm, instead of just the thread? If you set a watch on the variable instead of using a breakpoint, does that change anything?

Comment: I debugged plain old Java on my local machine with a Oracle Java 1.6.27. I do not debug a special expression. I tried to inspect a variable in the (x)=Variables tab. The thread in the Debug tab show the message after a second or two. To set a watch point, I have not tried, yet. I will do tomorrow.

Comment: The watch point does not change it, it seems. The behaviour is similar.

Comment: I could not reproduce this, the thread only goes into Suspended(Breakpoint line 4). Please add example code or even post a screenshot to something like: http://imgur.com/ . BTW which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: We have the issue only with production code (which I can not publish here) which has large data models (>2MB) attached. We saw the issue (repeatable and reproducable). After refactoring, we do not see the issue anymore... :-( It's quite strange. We would like to know what the issue was. We think it might by a cycle or something. We use Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. The 'Suspended' label is the normal to be expected behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger views sometimes execute the `toString()` method of objects to show the value. When your `toString()` method has a bug (infinite loop) or calls another buggy method, the debugger could run into problems.

Comment: How do I know where the bug is? Can I see the thing that is under this infinite evaluation? (Java)

Comment: The explanation might be correct, but I do not know it for sure. +1 and I accept it anyways. It is the best possible cause.

Comment: I cannot suspend to get a stack trace. How can I find out which toString() is causing the problem?

Comment: Having toString() write the content of a huge collection, for example, will hang the débugger.